# JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, ecmascript-5

I am new in python. Currently I am working on a project and I want a code which can extract numbers from text. I found a code on internet but it is written is java script. I want to run it in python but do not know how to do it. I tried js2py but it throws an exception that is supports only ECMA 5.1 but this code is in higher version. Can someone guide me how to run this code in python. Or someone who can convert this code into python code or ECMA 5.1 code.

```
const PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS = [
    // 775123456
    '[0-9]{6,15}',

    // 1(413)555-2378 or 1(413)555.2378 or 1 (413) 555-2378 or 1 (413) 555 2378 or (303) 494-2320
    '([0-9]{1,4}( )?)?\\([0-9]{2,4}\\)( )?[0-9]{2,4}(( )?(-|.))?( )?[0-9]{2,6}',

    // 1(262) 955-95-79 or 1(262)955.95.79
    '([0-9]{1,4}( )?)?\\([0-9]{2,4}\\)( )?[0-9]{2,4}(( )?(-|.))?( )?[0-9]{2,6}',

    // 413-577-1234-564
    '[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,6}',
    // 413-577-1234
    '[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,6}',
    // 413-577
    '[0-9]{2,4}-[0-9]{2,6}',

    // 413.577.1234.564
    '[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,6}',
    // 413.577.1234
    '[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,6}',
    // 413.577
    '[0-9]{2,4}\\.[0-9]{2,6}',

    // 413 577 1234 564
    '[0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{2,6}',
    // 413 577 1234
    '[0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{2,6}',
    // 123 4567
    '[0-9]{2,4} [0-9]{3,8}',
];

// All phones might be prefixed with '+' or '00'
for (let i = 0; i < PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS.length; i++) {
    PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS[i] = `(00|\\+)?${PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS[i]}`;
}

// The minimum number of digits a phone number can contain.
// That's because the PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS patterns are quite wide and report a lot of false positives.
const PHONE_MIN_DIGITS = 7;

// These are patterns that might be matched by PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS,
// but which are most likely not phone numbers. Add more patterns as needed.
const SKIP_PHONE_REGEXS = [
    // 2018-11-10
    '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$',
];
const PHONE_REGEX_GLOBAL = new RegExp(`(${PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS.join('|')})`, 'ig');
const PHONE_REGEX = new RegExp(`^(${PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS.join('|')})$`, 'i');
const SKIP_PHONE_REGEX = new RegExp(`^(${SKIP_PHONE_REGEXS.join('|')})$`, 'i');

/**
 * The function attempts to extract phone numbers from a text. Please note that
 * the results might not be accurate, since phone numbers appear in a large variety of formats and conventions.
 * If you encounter some problems, please [file an issue](https://github.com/apify/apify-js/issues).
 * @param {string} text Text to search the phone numbers in.
 * @return {string[]} Array of phone numbers found.
 * If no phone numbers are found, the function returns an empty array.
 * @memberOf social
 */
const phonesFromText = (text) => {
    if (!_.isString(text)) return [];

    let phones = text.match(PHONE_REGEX_GLOBAL) || [];
    phones = phones.filter((phone) => {
        if (!phone) return false;

        // Skip too short phones, they are most likely incorrect
        if (phone.match(/[0-9]/g).length < PHONE_MIN_DIGITS) return false;

        // Skip phone numbers matching specific patterns
        if (SKIP_PHONE_REGEX.test(phone)) return false;

        return true;
    });

    return phones;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you're new to python it can be an awesome way to get used to it!**
I suggest you try to translate the code yourself,
I will provide you with some guidelines to do it (ordered is by the given code):

1. in python const are not a thing, just delete the const word and it'll be fine
2. you probably know it but ';' are not a required thing either
3. loops in python are different but can be even more intuitive for your example-

```py
for i in len(PHONE_REGEXS_STRINGS):
    # code
```

4. '{' and '}' are not a thing, however tabs and ':' (where the '{' is) are required.
5. About regex, I'm not qualified to say for sure but I imagine it's pretty similar
6. About the last block of code- I'm not too sure, but i imagine it won't be too hard to do it in another way to get the same result.
7. functions in python are looking like:

```py
def funcName(param1, param2): # types are not a thing here either
    # code
    # more code
    return param1 # return types are yet another not-a-thing
```

8. Some little points- the word "let" can be deleted, "||" is "or" and "&&" is "and" and "!" is "not", "()" are not required in if's, for's and similar stuff, one-liners are totaly fine, and as you can see- comments are using '#' instead of "//".

Good luck, you can do it!

Comment: I know all other stuff but not expert in regx expression which is re module in python